# Anyone who's doing self study of bomb lab? The file doesn't be created correctly

Tags: tar

I'm trying to do self-study of csapp bomb lab.
I downloaded bomb32.tar file at http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/public/labs.html
but when I untag this file, I get only the 'bomb' exec file, not the readme text and bomb.c file.
Of course I can't run "gdb bomb", because it says 'there is no executable file'.

Is there anyone who has this kinda problem too? How did you solve it?

(I'm using Terminal at Macbook Air, and other labs work fine.)

Comment: It's a linux executable. You won't be able to run it on OS X. (I would recommended downloading VirtualBox and using it to run Ubuntu from within OS X.)

Comment: @AgentME Oh-oh. So I can't execute or compile this file just with Terminal? :(
Thanks for your comment!